# What's the difference when I plot 1/x,1/y vs 1./x,1.y

Tags: matlab

Given a set of data points for x as well as y, when I plot the data points and try to find a linear form for the plots, should I type

```
plot(1./x,1./y)
```

or

```
plot(1/x,1/y)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to take the reciprocal of each data point separately, not do any vector division (solution of a system of linear equations), so use `./`

Comment: @ayshaw: Yes, they are.  `logm` is the matrix version.